# jQuery UI Autocomplete with php and SQL not working

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

im new in php i get this code for jQuery but somthing worng happen i dunt know it ,
i have table name "drug_info" with columns "id, dru_name ,dru_code ,dru_unit , dru_price "
i want to Populate a Form with multi fields , when i try to write the drug name i chose from list then it auto complete the other fields related to the drug info , here is the codes .

this the PHP.

```
<?php

include '../modules/config.php';
$drugs = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM drug_info LIMIT 5 ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$items[] = $row;
} 


$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$matches = array();
foreach($drugs as $drug){
if(stripos($drug['name'], $term) !== false){

    $drug['value'] = $drug['name'];
    $drug['label'] = "{$drug['dru_name']}, {$drug['dru_code']}  {$drug['dru_unit']}";
    $matches[] = $drug;
}
}

$matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5);
print json_encode($matches);
?>
```

and this is the html.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var ac_config = {
    source: "xcore1.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#dru_name").val(ui.item.name);
        $("#dru_code").val(ui.item.code);
        $("#dru_unit").val(ui.item.unit
        );
    },
    minLength:1
};
$("#drug").autocomplete(ac_config);
});

</script>

<form action="#" method="post">
 <p><label for="name">Drug</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" /></p>
 <p><label for="code">Code</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="code" id="code" value="" /></p>
 <p><label for="zip">Unit</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="unit" id="unit" value="" /></p>
</form>
```

please i need help , thanx all

Comment: We understand something isn't working. What is it doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you have an empty array in $drugs. After that your code gets the data from the DB an puts it into the variable $items.

Thats okay so far, but then you're iterating over $drugs which is still empty?! What should your code do?

Comment: getting values from DB in array to use it later

Comment: I think sanjeev and me are right. Have you already try to figure out what your browser is getting back from the AJAX-Request?